# How to draw bounding box in tooljet?

Tags: labeling

I'm already using [tooljet](https://github.com/ToolJet/ToolJet) to classify some images. I'd like to expand it so that user can draw bounding boxes on the image.

Is there a way to draw bounding boxes on image in tooljet?

If there's no out of the box solution, are there some javascript (preferably) or python libraries that can be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

The bounding box component is in the roadmap of the ToolJet. We will update you as soon as we release it.
Please feel free to join [Community Slack](https://tooljet.com/slack) if you have more questions.